# DynamoDB update field only with larger value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am using DynamoDB to keep track of recently seen values in a dataset I'm working with.  My use case is:

- If the hash / sort key pair does not exist in DynamoDB, insert it with a count of the number of times we saw it and a TTL
- If the pair does exist in DynamoDB, increment a counter field by the number of times we saw it and update the TTL only if the new TTL is greater than the existing TTL

I want to do something like:

```
counter: int = 5
ttl: int = 1568585305

ddb_table.update_item(
        Key={'accountId': account_id, 'sourceIp': source_ip},
        UpdateExpression="SET #counter = if_not_exists(#counter, :start) + :inc SET #ttl = max(#ttl, ttl)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={'#counter': 'counter', '#ttl": 'ttl'},
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':inc': counter, ':start': 0}
    )
```

I realize `SET #ttl = max(#ttl, ttl)` is not valid, but is there anything else that would do what I want (i.e. only update the TTL with the new value if the new value is greater than the old value)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Contitional Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) to make "only update/insert/delete if `A` greater than `B`" checks.

However, I'm not sure what you mean by this:

> If the [hash / sort key] pair does exist in DynamoDB, increment a
>   counter field **by the number of times we saw it** and update the TTL
>   only if the new TTL is greater than the existing TTL

The HashKey/SortKey pair is the primary key of any DynamoDB table (see [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html)). This means you will only ever see one element of a specific HashKey/SortKey combination.

Comment: What I meant by “number of times we saw it”, is “number of times we saw it in the dataset” that I’m working with. The point of this app is to keep track of those pairs in the dataset.

Comment: Also won’t Conditional Expression result in performing the entire query or not performing the entire query based on the condition?  Remember, I want to increment the counter regardless of whether or not I update the TTL.

Comment: True, the conditional expression will cause the entire update to succeed or fail. If your condition only applies to part of the update, you might want to consider to make two separate updates (one for the counter, one for the TTL with condition).